# Is there a way to take a numeric variable, like the number 7, and turn it into a string of seven 1s?

Tags: r, function, survival

I'm wanting to run a Kaplan-Meier analysis on survival data but my survival variables run from 0-7 and KM only uses 0s and 1s. I'll provide some background in case it's helpful. This is seedling survival data. I planted 7 acorns per subplot (there are 3 treatment habitats represented in this data) and recorded survival multiple times over a 2.5 year period. Variables are: time, survival and habitat, the data below is a dataset similar to what my real data looks like.

```r
surva<-c(5,0,3, 2,0,0, 0,1,2, 3,0,1)
time<-c(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3)
habitat<-c("grassa", "grassb", "grassc", "grassa", "grassb", "grassc", "grassa", "grassb", "grassc", "grassa", "grassb", "grassc")
```

[image]

I want to turn my survival metrics into 1s (so they represent the seedlings that are alive in each habitat subplot) but I will also need to create duplicates of the corresponding cells (time and habitat) to go with the survival data. I appreciate any insight.

Comment: For rows with 0 , are you ok with them being dropped from the dataset as having no survivors?

Comment: Paul, no, I'll need to keep the data with 0s.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick - I'm not sure I can visualise what you are after?  Also, it looks like time and habitiat are locked in a pattern - is that just the example data or is it a feature of the real dataset?

Comment: That's just a feature of this simulated data. Hmm, maybe I'm thinking about this incorrectly.

Comment: My best guess is that your `surva` column shows the number of survivors for a particular `time` and `habitat`. To run a survival analysis you would typically have 1 row per individual and columns indicating `time` and `status` (1 for dead, 0 for alive) at that time. If there aren't time-varying covariates (as appears to be the case here), then the only time point needed is the last observation for each individual. Is that your goal?

Comment: Yes, Gregor that's what I'm trying to do. I think you are right. I can just sum the survivors at time 1 and compare them to the sum of time 2 on so on and so forth. (Time and habitat are not covariates in my real data.) Thx

Comment: For the poor souls that were misguided by the question's title, try `strrep("1", 7)` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe this is helpful:

```
library(tidyverse)
df |> 
  mutate(surva = lapply(surva, \(x) paste0(c(rep(1, times = x), rep(0, times = 7-x)), collapse = ""))) |>
  separate_longer_position(surva, width = 1)
```

gives:

```
   surva time habitat
1      1    1  grassa
2      1    1  grassa
3      1    1  grassa
4      1    1  grassa
5      1    1  grassa
6      0    1  grassa
7      0    1  grassa
8      0    2  grassb
9      0    2  grassb
10     0    2  grassb
11     0    2  grassb
12     0    2  grassb
13     0    2  grassb
14     0    2  grassb
15     1    3  grassc
16     1    3  grassc
17     1    3  grassc
18     0    3  grassc
19     0    3  grassc
20     0    3  grassc
21     0    3  grassc
22     1    1  grassa
23     1    1  grassa
24     0    1  grassa
25     0    1  grassa
26     0    1  grassa
27     0    1  grassa
28     0    1  grassa
29     0    2  grassb
30     0    2  grassb
31     0    2  grassb
32     0    2  grassb
33     0    2  grassb
34     0    2  grassb
35     0    2  grassb
36     0    3  grassc
37     0    3  grassc
38     0    3  grassc
39     0    3  grassc
40     0    3  grassc
41     0    3  grassc
42     0    3  grassc
43     0    1  grassa
44     0    1  grassa
45     0    1  grassa
46     0    1  grassa
47     0    1  grassa
48     0    1  grassa
49     0    1  grassa
50     1    2  grassb
51     0    2  grassb
52     0    2  grassb
53     0    2  grassb
54     0    2  grassb
55     0    2  grassb
56     0    2  grassb
57     1    3  grassc
58     1    3  grassc
59     0    3  grassc
60     0    3  grassc
61     0    3  grassc
62     0    3  grassc
63     0    3  grassc
64     1    1  grassa
65     1    1  grassa
66     1    1  grassa
67     0    1  grassa
68     0    1  grassa
69     0    1  grassa
70     0    1  grassa
71     0    2  grassb
72     0    2  grassb
73     0    2  grassb
74     0    2  grassb
75     0    2  grassb
76     0    2  grassb
77     0    2  grassb
78     1    3  grassc
79     0    3  grassc
80     0    3  grassc
81     0    3  grassc
82     0    3  grassc
83     0    3  grassc
84     0    3  grassc
```

Is that the sort of thing you were after?

Comment: YES! This is what I had in mind! Thx

Comment: @CristinaTarahumara Glad to hear it.  If this sorts the problem you had, please click the tick next to my answer.  This marks it as "answered" so other users know you're not still looking for help with this question.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you want to uncount, i.e. have 5 records for every record labelled with a 5; apart from that you dont want 0 records from records labelled 0; so the answer is to divide (and conquer).
first set aside the zero rows,
then work on the positive rows, simply uncound them
then recombine

```
in_1 <- data.frame(
  surva=c(5,0,3, 2,0,0, 0,1,2, 3,0,1),
  time=c(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3),
  habitat=c("grassa", "grassb", "grassc", "grassa", "grassb", "grassc", "grassa", "grassb", "grassc", "grassa", "grassb", "grassc")
)
library(tidyverse)

(recs_eq_0 <- filter(in_1,
                    surva==0))

(recs_gt_0_prep <- filter(in_1,
                      surva>0))

(recs_gt_0 <- uncount(recs_gt_0_prep,
        weights = surva) |> mutate(surva=1L))

(fin <- bind_rows(recs_eq_0,
          recs_gt_0) )
```